# How to handle streaming response from restful webservice in flex 4 using HTTPService?

Tags: apache-flex

Is it possible to handle streaming data from restful webservice(webservices are deployed on Tomcat server) using  through HTTP Get method.
I am using  to access the resful webservice on Tomcat Server which returns the streaming data.
Code:

```
<s:HTTPService  id="getList" url="<rest webservice url>" showBusyCursor="true" useProxy="false" method="GET" resultFormat="xml" result="resultHandler(event)" fault="faultHandler(event)" >

 <s:request xmlns="">
 <sessionid>a3a1d1f1-cf55-465e-b369-0c484d8ec38f</sessionid>
 </s:request>
 </s:HTTPService>
```

The above webservice actually returns some device records from the server, if the records are less say somewhere about 10 or 20 , I am able to see the data in the result event.But suppose there are some 1000 records which needs to be sent in a series of packets, result event is not generated.
Any inputs on how to receive the complete data so that it can be used to display on the datagrid?

Answer (score 0):

If you are only making a GET request, use the URLStream class instead of HTTPService.  This does what you want and lets you access the data in packets as it comes across.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response.I am trying to use URLStream class , since it is only a GET request.I am trying to read the stream data in ProgressEvent handler and update the dataprovider for the grid in which I need to display this stream data dynamically.If this does not work out should I go for BlazeDs or Adobe LCDs?

Comment: No, URLStream should work for what you described.  If you run into any issues just post your questions back here.  You can also use Socket() for this... but URLStream should get the job done.

Comment: I am using URLStream and facing some issue in stream read,have posted the issue down in the below thread.Please have a look at the same.

Comment: Now I am able to read the data in progress event, there was some communication issue.Is there any way I can parse the stream data as an xml , since I dont have control on the stream